# "My" action of waking up early exhausted me. -> can "My" be changed to "The"?

Tags: usage

Imagine I woke up particularly early today. Now in the afternoon, I am exhausted. I want to express this fact by using "action of" as the subject of the sentence.

**Question 1:**
What article should I use? **the** or **my**?

**Question 2:**
Are they different in meaning?

**Example 1:**

> **The** action of waking up early exhausted me.

**Example 2:**

> **My** action of waking up early exhausted me.

**Example 3:**

Probably the most idiomatic one.

> Waking up early exhausted me.

Comment: It wasn't the action of waking that exhausted you; you were tired later in the day _because_ you had been awake for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

**the** sounds more natural than **my**. And you are correct, Example 3 sounds the most natural. I don't think anyone would normally say Example 1 or 2.

They don't differ in meaning significantly.